How are individual spool optimal speeds determined in 3-spool engines like Trent 700/800?
I can see that in a 3-spool engine, the low pressure turbine and the fan have the lowest speed; The intermediate pressure turbine and the intermediate pressure compressor have another speed, and the last spool, which is the high pressure turbine connected with the high pressure compressor, has the highest speed.
As far as I know, Rolls-Royce implemented this design on Trent 700/800 engines to insure every part of jet engine works at its optimal speed.
My question is: How can they find the best speed for each spool? What tools are used? Or are tests conducted to figure out exactly the optimal speed per spool?

The most determinant factor is air pressure varies along the compressor stages, and along the turbine stages. This requires adjusting the air duct cross-section, and in turn the blade size, which implies changing the blades angular velocities.

Brief engine description
Taking only the compressor into account (the reasoning is similar for the turbine): It is composed of stages, each stage is made of a rotating disk with blades (rotor), and stationary vanes (stator). The rotor role is to accelerate air, the stator role is to convert the excess of air velocity created by the blades into pressure.

(Trent engine, source: Danish Anwar's work at Behance.net)
Hence, as air progresses along the compressor ducting, pressure is progressively increased while velocity is kept more or less constant. The duct itself is annular with inner and outer walls. Blades and vanes are located between walls, vanes are fixed to the outer wall, and blades are fixed to solid rotating disks forming the inner wall.
General annular duct design
At each stage, air velocity relatively to the rotor blade is the vector sum of the flow velocity along the engine axis and the blade tangential velocity, the latter varying along the blade length. It means the total air velocity relative to a blade depends on the angular velocity of the rotor, the outer diameter of the duct and the blades length, which can all vary between stages. There is a first choice to be made: What should be the duct inner and outer diameters for each stage? But this can't be answered directly.
As air moves from one stage to the next, its mass doesn't change but its volume decreases as its pressure increases. The design of the next stage must take this into account: The cross-section of the annular ducting must be smaller. This means changing the geometry of the blades (and vanes of the same stage), either the diameter of the rotor disk, or the length of the rotor blades, or both. This is another choice, based on air velocity where it is the largest, at the blades tip.
If the next stage is on the same spool, the angular velocity is the same but velocity of air at the blades tip is different due to the different outer diameter. This means some compromise is required to select the angular velocity and/or the diameters.
Blade efficiency
Engineers have a general design constraint: Compressor efficiency. Pressure increase is provided by vanes according to air acceleration, efficiency is first a matter of efficiency in air acceleration by the blades. This is achieved by using a high flow velocity at the blade tip, a fraction of the speed of sound (speed of sound for the fan).
The compressor must deliver the air flow required by the combustion chamber. The more powerful the engine, the larger this flow. This can be achieved by:

A larger air duct cross-section, which leads to a larger duct diameter and a larger engine, or
A larger angular velocity which leads to more noise and possibly a lower efficiency.

This defines the outer diameter of the duct for a given stage. As the cross section is defined by the pressure at this location, the inner diameter is also dependent on the outer diameter.
There is a compromise to be accepted: Velocity varies along the blade length. The same cross-section can be obtained with a shorter blade if the outer diameter is larger, this limits the velocity variation along the blade length. A smaller variation means mean velocity is closer to the optimum. But a shorter blade requires a larger chord (width), decreasing the aspect ratio, which in turn decreases the efficiency, so another compromise is to be decided when selecting the outer diameter of a stage.
Mass and other mechanical considerations
Engineer have more constraints, including minimal mass, minimal deformation, and minimal lag when changing thrust, which influence the blade size, hence the duct shape and the angular velocity for each stage.
However having a different angular velocity for each stage would add mechanical complexity, mass and weak points. The current choice is to limit the number of different velocities to two or three, giving engines with two or three spools. Rolls-Royce designed a 3-spool engine in the late 60s (RB.203), and maintained this choice until today with the Trent family.
Spool velocity
For a given spool, choosing its angular velocity is a matter of averaging the angular velocities or all the stages on the same spool. This can be a challenge, especially if the engine is a turbofan: The fan is used both for the cold flow (bypass air) and the core flow, it cannot be efficient for both flows unless using a dedicated spool for the fan.
A reasoning similar to the previous one can be applied to the turbine stages. Indeed the number of angular velocities in the turbine must equal the number of angular velocities in the compressor. For each spool the turbine section role is to spin the compressor/fan section on the same spool.
The angular velocity of a spool is also a compromise between the angular velocity required for the compressor and the one required for the turbine. In the process of optimization, the tip velocities and the duct diameters can be adjusted for the optimal match.
Stall prevention
In order for the compressor to work, the air flow must be continuous. The engine is optimized for a working point (take off or cruise) and the different spools are optimized to deliver this homogeneous flow in spite of the different angular velocities.
When thrust demand is changes a new fuel rate is set in the combustion chamber, this introduces a new regime for the engine, spool velocities are changed. This can lead to breaking the flow homogeneity between spools, leading to blade stall, especially for a 2-spool engine, as the design point may not be as optimal.
Stall prevention greatly relies on the introduction of another parameter, the vane angle of attack of the first stages. For some Trent engines, it consists in the first four stages of the intermediate spool being equipped with variable (adjustable AoA) vanes.
Environmental constraints
Constraints like noise and pollutants rejection minimization greatly influence the velocity the fan and its size/mass. Using three spools, with one dedicated to the fan, might be a great advantage, each spool being better optimized, meaning less fuel required to spin it, hence less pollution.
Conclusion
In conclusion, a spool angular velocity is a compromise between between multiple factors, in order to find the best efficiency:

Best match between compressor and turbine sections
Best match between duct diameters for the stages on a given spool.
Best mass/velocity choice for the blades
Best homogeneity in the flow to prevent compressor stall.

This is first a matter of computation: Duct area and air velocity at the tip of a blade are straightforward. Finding compromises between stages given a number of spools is also relatively easy. Then tests on the engine prototype are conducted to check the validity of the choices at varying thrust demands, adjustments are done.
See also: : Why does the Trent XWB have intermediate compressor stages?
